# PHP data is endless loading, jquery, phonegap

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, cordova

I'm working on an iOS app with phonegap and jQuery mobile.

When I make an AJAX request to a PHP file which includes just a simple 1 to 10 counter (and echoes these numbers), everything is fine and shows up when the app starts.

But when I request a PHP file which is a little bit more complex, the app is loading and loading and loading and nothing happens.

Here's the PHP file

```
<?php           
    include 'connect.php';

    $data = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM pics ORDER BY `date` DESC') or die(mysql_error()); 

    while($info = mysql_fetch_array( $data )) 
    {
        <div id='thumbwrapper'>";
        Echo "<img src=../images/".$info['thumb']." class='thumb'></a>";
        Echo "</div></a>";
    }
?>
```

And here's the ajax request

```
<script typ="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#randomdiv").load("http://localhost/test.php");
    });
</script>

<div id="randomdiv"></div>
```

PS: and yes, I've added "*" to the ExternalHosts in cordova.plist

EDIT 1: i think i know where the problem is. today i wanted to let me show the test.php file via another browser (firefox), and this browser asked me for a username and password, before he showed me the php file.

maybe the app is loading and loading and loading because nobody inputs a username and passwort. my question is, where could i explain what the username and passwort is?! (in the app). or where could I switch this thing off in xampp? (username (xampp) and passwort (empty) are the standard things).

thanks.

Comment: http://localhost/test.php  how is it ..is it endless ..then fixi it

Comment: Well, thanks, but this shows me the correct and expected results, so thats why I don't understand it. In the browser it's ok, but the app is doing nothing!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok guys, thanks for the help. the problem was that the one folder in the xampp folder (where the php file was) needed a username and password (also via browser). i didn't get it how i could explain the jquery syntax the username and password, so i copied the php file to another folder in the xampp folder. and now everything is working (no need for username and password). by the way, i also don't get why i need for just one folder a username and password.

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
while($info = mysql_fetch_array( $data )) 
{
    <div id='thumbwrapper'>";
    Echo "<img src=../images/".$info['thumb']." class='thumb'></a>";
    Echo "</div></a>";
}
```

with

```
while($info = mysql_fetch_array( $data )) 
{
    echo '<div id="thumbwrapper">';
    echo '<img src="../images/'.$info['thumb'].' class="thumb">';
    echo '</div>';
}
```

and

```
<script typ="text/javascript">
```

with

```
<script type="text/javascript">
```

Comment: thanks, but these were just typos. i've changed what you've said, but the app is always loading and does nothing.

Comment: If you open the page directly, do you get any error(s)? Did you check your PHP error log file? The behaviour the page is exhibiting is usually as a result of the web server returning any HTTP code other than `200`, such as a `404` or (more likely in this case) `500`.

Comment: That's the curious thing. If i open the php file via browser directly, everything works like it should!

Answer (score 0):

try to give the path like this

```
$('#result').load('ajax/test.html');
```

instead of loaclhost .. as it is working from browser.

Comment: i've copied the hole app folder into the xampp folder, so that I could write the path you said (like "../../test.php"). now is the app starting, but ignores completely the whole php-file...